# JAXB XML -> Java object attribute

Tags: jaxb

My XML Structure.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A>
    <B ID="www">
        <C>abcde</C>
    </B>
</A>
```

---

I use `Unmarshaller`.

```java
System.out.println(c.toString());   => abcde
```

I want attribute information.

```java
System.out.println(????????);        => ID or count
```

help me please.

Comment: What object model are you mapping the XML to?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following

**JAVA MODEL**

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations require that you have an object model to convert your XML documents to.

***A***

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public class A {

    private B b;

    @XmlElement(name="B")
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

***B***

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class B {

    private String id;
    private String c;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "C")
    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

**DEMO CODE**

Once you have your XML converted to Java objects, you can navigate your objects to get the desired data.

***Demo***

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14951650/input.xml");
        A a = (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(a.getB().getId());
        System.out.println(a.getB().getC());
    }

}
```

***Output***

```
www
abcde
```